# How to make backgounds for all select have pointer-events: none;

Tags: css

Can I make css for element according other css attributes by using css.
I have many js codes that make pointer-events: none; to make select non selectable.
I want to make gray background  according this **pointer-events: none;**

Comment: You should provide your css and js code for better suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't select by CSS attribute. But you could simply set a class with `js` and apply both attributes to that class `pointer-events none` and `background-color: grey`.

**Working example:**

```js
document.querySelector('select').classList.add('disabled');
```

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```